# Nodejs library RequestJS undefined MULTER req.files.fileName.path when use ExpressJS routes

Tags: node.js, express, undefined, multer, requestjs

I got a problem with Multer, undefined req.files.path field

First, my Express.js   route is:

**routes.js**

```
    router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
    // id, name, usersArray[], info, iconImg, headerImg
    var dataObject = new MyMongooseDataObject();
    // Receive data
    dataObject.id = uuid.v4();
    dataObject.name = req.body.name;
    dataObject.usersArray = req.body.usersArray;
    dataObject.info = req.body.info;

    return someBindingWrapperToStoreTheFile.postFile(uuid.v4(), [req.files.iconImg.path.toString(), req.files.headerImg.path.toString()])
        .then(function (postedFiles) {
            dataObject.iconImg = postedFiles.body.payload.files[0].id;
            dataObject.headerImg = postedFiles.body.payload.files[1].id;
            //save dataObject after storing images and processing data
            dataObject.save(function(savedDataObject){
                next(success(req, 200, 'dataObject Saved ' + savedDataObject.id));
            });
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log('FAILED: ', err.stack);
            return next(failure(req, 500, err));
        });
});
```

When I test my route with  a separate   small requestJS  script, it **works** just fine:

**HTTP rest api request  test with requestJS**

***postDataObject.js***

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var uuid = require('uuid');

var formData = {
    name: 'someName',
    info: 'Some INFO and text description. ',
    'usersArray[0][uuid]': uuid.v4().toString(),
    'usersArray[1][uuid]': uuid.v4().toString(),
    'usersArray[2][uuid]': uuid.v4().toString(),
    // handle files
    iconImg: fs.createReadStream('/var/tmp/img/iconImg.png'),
    headerImg: fs.createReadStream('/var/tmp/img/headerImg.png')
};

request.post({url:'http://127.0.0.1:2233/api/postDataObject', formData: formData}, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('failed:', err);
    }
    console.log('DataObject creation is successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

Now I'm writing the wrapper library for the fronted usage, when I use the same code in another context, it seems, that Multer handling **req.files.headerImg.path**  is not working, it's undefined.

The code I use for wrapper library:

**wrapper-lib.js**

```
var request = require('request'),
    URI = require('URIjs'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    uuid = require('uuid'),
    path = require('path'),
    Promise = require('bluebird'),
    _ = require('lodash'),


DataObjectBindings.prototype.createDataObject = function (jsonRequestJSFormData) {
    var self = this;
               // this give the URL of the API to make requests to
    return self.getAPIurlHelper().then(function (apiUrl) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                request.post({url: apiUrl, form: jsonRequestJSFormData}, function (err, res, body) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        resolve({res: res, body: JSON.parse(body)});
                    };
                }); //end of .post
            });   // end of  Promise 
        });  // end of getAPIurlHelper() function
}; // end of createDataObject function definition
```

And Finally I test the warpper with:

**wrapper-test.js**

```
// Instantiate Broker Client
var Wrapper = require('./wrapper-lib');

var wi;   //wrapper instalnce
var ConnectApiRequestTracer = require('./connectApiRequestTracer');
var fs = require('fs');

    ConnectApiRequestTracer().connect()
    .then(function () {
        wi = new Wrapper();

        return wi.createDataObject(
            uuid.v4(),
            {
                name: 'Some Cool Name',
                info: 'Some nice description and info. ',
                'usersArray[0][uuid]': uuid.v4().toString(),
                'usersArray[1][uuid]': uuid.v4().toString(),
                'usersArray[2][uuid]': uuid.v4().toString(),
                iconImg: fs.createReadStream('/var/tmp/img/iconImg.png'),
                headerImg: fs.createReadStream('/var/tmp/img/headerImg.png'),
        );
    })
    .then(function (data) {
console.log('SUCCESS: ', data);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('FAILED', err.stack);
    });
```

When I run the test case  wrapper-test.js, it throws me an error, that says the req.files.iconImg.path  is undefined.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try using :

- req.**file**.iconImg.path
- req.**file**.headerImg.path

instead of req.files.iconImg.path and req.files.headerImg.path